# How to fix the console warning "The resource ... was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, gatsby

I'm developing a gatsby theme/starter for PWA's, but I can't seem to get rid of the following console warning:

```
The resource https://davidde.github.io/gatsby-starter-simpwa/page-data/offline-plugin-app-shell-fallback/page-data.json
was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event.
Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
```

On first load everything works fine; the service worker registers like it should and there is no warning. However, after reloading, this warning shows up. This makes no sense since the `as` value is set to 'fetch'.
I'm assuming it has something to do with the configuration of `gatsby-plugin-offline` or maybe `gatsby-plugin-manifest`.

The source code is at https://github.com/davidde/gatsby-starter-simpwa,
and it's deployed to https://davidde.github.io/gatsby-starter-simpwa/.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this?

Comment: i'm running into a similar issue, how you found a solution to this?

Comment: Just ran into the problem today.

Answer (score 1):

The warning simply means that the resource is getting downloaded with a higher priority but it is not getting used with the same urgency with which it was downloaded.

The expectation of browser when it sees a link with `rel=preload` is that the resource is critical for the page to render properly. But when that is not the case, it is warning you to may be defer the download so that it can do something else (like downloading CSS or rendering layout) that is more important than downloading this no-so-important resource. More here -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload

### Possible Solution

You can check if the offline-plugin takes options to `defer` the resource download and/or move it to `<body>` instead of adding to `<head>` when bundling and injecting link to scripts into the HTML.

Answer (score -1):

**In public folder in react app here is an index.html paste this line inside index.html and try again to run react app**

```
<link rel="preload" href="fonts/cicle_fina-webfont.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Gatsby apps aren't the same as CRA apps, and don't have an index.html.